# How to check a video for unpublished captions on any youtube video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to build an automated program that alerts me if there are draft captions on a video. Recently there have been some vulgar captions that were added to my videos but were caught as drafts.

I'm using this sample as a base but when I try checking videos it only provides published video caption information. I've looked at the api documentation and it appears that I should see the captions in draft status as well.

https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/captions.py

```
def get_authenticated_service(args):
  flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scope=YOUTUBE_READ_WRITE_SSL_SCOPE,
    message=MISSING_CLIENT_SECRETS_MESSAGE)

  storage = Storage("%s-oauth2.json" % sys.argv[0])
  credentials = storage.get()

  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run_flow(flow, storage, args)

  # Trusted testers can download this discovery document from the developers page
  # and it should be in the same directory with the code.
  with open("youtube-v3-api-captions.json", "r") as f:
    doc = f.read()
    return build_from_document(doc, http=credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http()))


# Call the API's captions.list method to list the existing caption tracks.
def list_captions(youtube, video_id):
  results = youtube.captions().list(
    part="snippet",
    videoId=video_id

  ).execute()

  for item in results["items"]:
    id = item["id"]
    name = item["snippet"]["name"]
    language = item["snippet"]["language"]
    print("Caption track '%s(%s)' in '%s' language." % (name, id, language))

  return results["items"]

args = argparser.parse_args()
youtube = get_authenticated_service(args)

print(list_captions(youtube,"my-video"))
```

I expect print(list_captions(youtube,"my-video")) to print to my console information on all the captions available to a video including captions that are in draft mode in different languages. I ran a test on one of my videos, I'm expecting draft caption track in polish to appear but only english and the auto captions appear:

```
Caption track '(XP6L39GAE3cGDethMwzyWkLZChESxt5MnCNokggzJnY=)' in 'ja' language.
Caption track '(zKBRyKIAn6BOtdpekvePw4qtM-_w7Jcv)' in 'en' language.
[{'kind': 'youtube#caption', 'etag': '"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/9AEECTD98uML9khnVlJ9I3nZyBk"', 'id': 'XP6L39GAE3cGDethMwzyWkLZChESxt5MnCNokggzJnY=', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'RYx1P_z9tNk', 'lastUpdated': '2019-02-20T09:07:56.247Z', 'trackKind': 'ASR', 'language': 'ja', 'name': '', 'audioTrackType': 'unknown', 'isCC': False, 'isLarge': False, 'isEasyReader': False, 'isDraft': False, 'isAutoSynced': False, 'status': 'serving'}}, {'kind': 'youtube#caption', 'etag': '"Bdx4f4ps3xCOOo1WZ91nTLkRZ_c/kxbjbXbUxo9fiHaH8bj_pUuttwg"', 'id': 'zKBRyKIAn6BOtdpekvePw4qtM-_w7Jcv', 'snippet': {'videoId': 'RYx1P_z9tNk', 'lastUpdated': '2019-02-20T16:43:48.873Z', 'trackKind': 'standard', 'language': 'en', 'name': '', 'audioTrackType': 'unknown', 'isCC': False, 'isLarge': False, 'isEasyReader': False, 'isDraft': False, 'isAutoSynced': False, 'status': 'serving'}}]
Caption track '(XP6L39GAE3cGDethMwzyWkLZChESxt5MnCNokggzJnY=)' in 'ja' language.
Caption track '(zKBRyKIAn6BOtdpekvePw4qtM-_w7Jcv)' in 'en' language.
```

---

*Screenshot about the captions exist on the video:*

[image: What captions exist on the video]

Comment: Please [edit] your question with the current results of `print(list_captions(youtube,"my-video"))`.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave I've updated it with my current output. I've tried several different videos. Ones I own and ones my friends own as well as videos that are public vs unlisted. If there are captions in draft mode they will never display in the output.

Comment: can you verify in YouTube - not using the API - how many drafts your video `RYx1P_z9tNk` has at the moment? - I think that YouTube API is not working as expected for retrieve the captions, or the video not longer has those drafts you don't desire.

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave Yes I can it shows what captions are there as drafts as video owner and you can usually check what the captions say even if you aren't a video owner. See above for a screenshot of what subs are available on the video.

Comment: There should be only one draft which is the only one I created as a test.

Comment: Stedos, Hmm, strange, using the [try-it feature in YouTube official documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/captions/list?apix=true&apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%22snippet%22%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22loT_kPl-hJE%22%2C%22alt%22%3A%22json%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22items(id%2Ckind%2Csnippet)%22%2C%22prettyPrint%22%3Atrue%7D) and [Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.captions.list?part=snippet&videoId=RYx1P_z9tNk&fields=items(id%252Ckind%252Csnippet)&_h=4&), I can't each the results you show in the screenshot.

Comment: If there's a chance you can use F12 devleoper tools "Google Chrome", and check the "Network" tab for see the requests made for retrieve the drafts, you might find out how retrieve these items.